# Rxjs zip with rest call called twice

Tags: angular, rxjs, rxjs6

I've usecase wherein call HTTP get request, get a list of objects, get a distinct values of one of the properties of the object and call another HTTP request, then enrich the objects with response from second HTTP request. Below is code snippet I had written.

```
const retrieveData = this.http.get('/url1');
const retreiveNameMap = retrieveData.pipe(map(e=>KUtils.distinct(e)), switchMap(e=>this.http.get('/url2',e)));

const source = zip(retrieveData, retreiveNameMap).subscribe(e=>console.log(e));
```

However when I debug in browser, I notice that there is two HTTP request being triggered for `url1`(first HTTP request), how to avoid calling `url1` twice?

Comment: well you are calling it twice, so I guess it's expected ;) Question is probably why are you calling it twice? You don't seem to need `zip` here at all?

Comment: Problem is that I want to access both response values not just last http request, hence used zip.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it's being run twice bc you're calling it twice, one in zip, and at the start of retrieveNameMap... you don't need zip at all here.

```
const retrieveData = this.http.get('/url1');
const retreiveNameMap = retrieveData.pipe(
  switchMap(e1=>this.http.get('/url2',KUtils.distinct(e1)).pipe(map(e2 => [e1, e2])))
);

const source = retreiveNameMap.subscribe(e=>console.log(e));
```